# Reading cfg file into array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have one cfg file that is using this format:

```
H: user2986 pass2986
H: user3258 pass3258 # { startdate=2015-05-15 | enddate=2015-11-17 |  info=girlfriend data | dealer=x-admin }

FILE CHANNELINFO: "/other/config.cfg"
```

So i need only to read into array this:

```
$array[user] = user2986
$array[pass] = pass2986
$array[startdate] = '';
$array[enddate]   = '';
$array[info]      = '';
$array[dealer]    = '';

$array[user] = user3258
$array[pass] = pass3258
$array[startdate] = '2015-05-15';
$array[enddate]   = '2015-11-17';
$array[info]      = 'girlfriend data';
$array[dealer]    = 'x-admin';
```

How to do that in PHP? I try to read file but i don't know how to parse H: tag and put this in while loop into array...any example code?

Thanks

Comment: Show your attempt(s).

Comment: That's not a very useful config format to begin with. Did it materialize by itself? Shouldn't there already be an extractor if that's how it got generated? Why not use the database for *per-user* configuration data?

Comment: this is config file from one software...i need to read it into array so that i can then show it in datatables  with add edit and delete buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function:

It works for given data, which is very limited.

```
function parseCfg($file) {
    $cfg = array();

    foreach (file($file) as $line) {
        if (preg_match('/H: ([A-za-z0-9]+) ([A-za-z0-9]+)( # (\{.*?\})){0,1}/', $line, $match)) {
            $data = array(
                'user' => $match[1], 
                'pass' => $match[2], 
                'startdate' => '', 
                'enddate' => '', 
                'info' => '',
                'dealer' => ''
            );

            if (isset($match[4])) {
                $pretty = str_replace(array('  ', ' | '), array(' ', '&'), substr($match[4], 2, -2));

                parse_str($pretty, $additional);

                $data = array_merge($data, $additional);
            }

            $cfg[] = $data;
        }
    }

    return $cfg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...i now implemet your code...and php script stop working at $pretty = str_replace(array('  ', ' | '), [' ', '&'], substr($match[4], 2, -2)); could you please see why? or give jsfiddle link with demo

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? In my code I used [] as array, if you are using PHP < 5.4, swap [' ', '&'] with array(' ', '&');

Comment: thanks...i im using PHP < 5.4..now it all works...but i want to me short code...could you please write how to fix this? on this code php code hangs :  $data = [
                'user' => $match[1], 
                'pass' => $match[2], 
                'startdate' => '', 
                'enddate' => '', 
                'info' => '',
                'dealer' => ''
            ];

Comment: so i write this replacement code:$data['user']     = $match[1];
     $data['pass']     = $match[2];
     $data['startdate'] = '0000-00-00';
     $data['enddate']   = '0000-00-00';
     $data['info']      = '';
     $data['dealer']    = 'NONE';

Comment: it is ok code but your is simpler and shorter...i think is because i im using PHP < 5.4 so what do i need to change? All code is working perfect...so this minor change i need to add and all is then working excellent

Comment: I changed the code to work with PHP < 5.4. Simply with PHP 5.4 you can use [] as replacement with array.

Comment: thanks...now it works:) Now i can read and display it in datatables...now i need to add new line and edit line with changes...thanks:)

Comment: It you need any additional help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'H: user2986 pass2986
H: user3258 pass3258 # { startdate=2015-05-15 | enddate=2015-11-17 |  info=girlfriend data | dealer=x-admin }

FILE CHANNELINFO: "/other/config.cfg"';

$expStr = explode("\n", $str);

for ($i=0;$i<count($expStr);$i++) {
$exp2Str = explode(" ", $expStr[$i]);
var_dump($exp2Str);
}
```

Is this a starting point for you?

Just delete the useless data and then add the rest to the array in the loop!

Of course that only works if the string is always the same!

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "H:"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "user2986"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "pass2986
"
}
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "H:"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "user3258"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "pass3258"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "#"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "{"
  [5]=>
  string(20) "startdate=2015-05-15"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "|"
  [7]=>
  string(18) "enddate=2015-11-17"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "|"
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
  [10]=>
  string(15) "info=girlfriend"
  [11]=>
  string(4) "data"
  [12]=>
  string(1) "|"
  [13]=>
  string(14) "dealer=x-admin"
  [14]=>
  string(2) "}
"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "
"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "FILE"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "CHANNELINFO:"
  [2]=>
  string(19) ""/other/config.cfg""
}
```